# iOS: Having problems with self-signed certificate. SSL Handshake Error (-9824)

Tags: ios, ssl, certificate, self-signed

I have an application where I need to perform sort of a 2-Step-Authentication and long story short I'm getting per-user base64 encoded pem format certificates from the server and using them on each request.

First I generate a key pair, make a CSR, give them the CSR, they give me the certificate and this is where I have to use it and fail. I'm getting the following errors in the console for each individual request:

**CFNetwork SSLHandshake failed (-4)**

**CFNetwork SSLHandshake failed (-9824)**

**CFNetwork SSLHandshake failed (-9824)**

**NSURLConnection/CFURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9824)**

My approach is the following:

-grab the DER encoded data from the PEM formatted signed certificate they are sending me

-make a SecCertificateRef which I add to the keychain

-query for the SecIdentityRef in the keychain by label

-I then do some mostly needless stuff like grab the SecCertificateRef and private key from the identity mostly to be sure what's going on

-I also insert a CA Certificate which I have from the server and grab a reference to it from the keychain (not sure if I need to use it for the credential but I tried with or without it - the result was the same)

-I then initialize the credential with the identity and my certificates and use it when I get a NSURLAuthenticationMethodClientCertificate auth method (I don't do the check but that's all I get besides the server trust).

So up to this point nothing is NULL, everything gets initialized and looks good but the requests don't succeed. When I try to use the server trust credential on all  requests, I get through and don't get the error but my server is giving me a security error as it should. As soon as I use the custom credential for any challenge I get the above errors.

*note: I know the code is messy and I shouldn't be inserting certificates on each request but it's still very early work in progress and that's not the problem since the refs get instantiated correctly*

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection willSendRequestForAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge{
    SSLConnectionWrapper *wrapper = [self wrapperForConnection:connection];


    NSString *certStringBase64 = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] SSLCertificateForUserWithID:wrapper.userID];
    NSData *certData = [[NSData alloc] initWithBase64EncodedString:certStringBase64 options:0];
    NSString *certString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:certData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    certString = [certString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----" withString:@""];
    certString = [certString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"-----END CERTIFICATE-----" withString:@""];
    certString = [[certString componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet]] componentsJoinedByString:@""];
    //at this point certString contains the DER encoded certificate data

    SecCertificateRef cert = SecCertificateCreateWithData(NULL, (__bridge CFDataRef)([[NSData alloc] initWithBase64EncodedString:certString options:kNilOptions]));

    OSStatus err = SecItemAdd((__bridge CFDictionaryRef) [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                                          (__bridge id) kSecClassCertificate, kSecClass,
                                                          cert, kSecValueRef,
                                                          kCFBooleanTrue, kSecReturnPersistentRef,
                                                          [NSString stringWithFormat:@"CertLabel_UserID_%@", wrapper.userID], kSecAttrLabel,
                                                          nil], NULL);

    const void *keys[] =   { kSecClass, kSecReturnRef,  kSecAttrLabel };

    const void *values[] = { kSecClassIdentity, kCFBooleanTrue, (__bridge const void *)([NSString stringWithFormat:@"CertLabel_UserID_%@", wrapper.userID]) };

    CFDictionaryRef queryForIdentityDict = CFDictionaryCreate(NULL, keys, values,
                                                              3, NULL, NULL);

    SecIdentityRef identityKeychainRef = NULL;
    OSStatus s = SecItemCopyMatching(queryForIdentityDict, (CFTypeRef *)&identityKeychainRef);

    SecCertificateRef certKeychainRef = NULL;
    OSStatus s2 = SecIdentityCopyCertificate(identityKeychainRef, &certKeychainRef);

    SecKeyRef privateKey;
    SecIdentityCopyPrivateKey(identityKeychainRef, &privateKey);

    NSString *stringForCACert = [self stringForCACert];

    SecCertificateRef caCert = SecCertificateCreateWithData(NULL, (__bridge CFDataRef)([[NSData alloc] initWithBase64EncodedString:stringForCACert options:kNilOptions]));
    OSStatus s3 = SecItemAdd((__bridge CFDictionaryRef) [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                                          (__bridge id) kSecClassCertificate, kSecClass,
                                                          caCert, kSecValueRef,
                                                           @"CACert", kSecAttrLabel,
                                                          nil], NULL);

    const void *keys1[] =   { kSecClass, kSecReturnRef,  kSecAttrLabel };

    const void *values1[] = { kSecClassCertificate, kCFBooleanTrue, @"CACert" };

    CFDictionaryRef queryForCACert = CFDictionaryCreate(NULL, keys1, values1,
                                                              3, NULL, NULL);

    SecCertificateRef caCertKeychainRef = NULL;
    OSStatus s4 = SecItemCopyMatching(queryForCACert, (CFTypeRef *)&caCertKeychainRef);

    NSURLCredential *credential = [[NSURLCredential alloc] initWithIdentity:identityKeychainRef certificates:@[ (__bridge id)certKeychainRef, (__bridge id) caCertKeychainRef] persistence:NSURLCredentialPersistencePermanent];

    if ([challenge.protectionSpace.authenticationMethod isEqualToString:NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust]) {

        [challenge.sender useCredential:[NSURLCredential credentialForTrust:challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust] forAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
    }else{
        [challenge.sender useCredential:credential forAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's an authentication challenge faced by server. You can bypass by following code (Using NSURLCOnnection)

```
+ (BOOL)allowsAnyHTTPSCertificateForHost:(NSString *)host {
    return YES;
}
```

**Note**: Don't use above if you uploading app on app store.

For iOS 9 above would not work, please edit plist as follows

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

Comment: I already had the AllowsArbitraryLoads enabled. I tried the category as well but it didn't do the trick. It gets called but it doesn't stop the handshake error from happening. It's also not tied to iOS 9's policy for TLS 1.2.